# Why are release branches made from develop and not master branch?

Tags: branch, git-flow

Git-flow explains the following process for release branches -

1. Release branch should be forked from develop branch
2. Release branch should merged back into master branch, and a tag created from master branch.

My question is why is why should release branches be forked from develop and not master? Is there any benefit from doing so? 
I can instead

1. Merge my develop into master
2. Fork a release from master and then tag the master...

How will that affect the version management?

Comment: Maybe the assumption is that there could be some long fixes or other work going into `master` which you would not want to appear in `develop`.

Comment: But the purpose of master is to be a "replica of a production ready stable code", as per GitFlow. so there should not be any fixes going on in master ideally, isn't it?

Comment: take a look at this answer [Alexey Andrushkevich answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39903624/9673980) or for more details :
[minas's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20755706/9673980)

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered your question in one of your comments:
`the purpose of master is to be a replica of a production ready stable code`

Let me elaborate on that:

1. That statement is correct. `master` is production-ready. According to `git-flow` every commit (being a merge from a `release` or `hotfix` branch) leads to a new release.
2. If you merge `develop` directly onto `master` you might end up with instabilities. That's what we create a `release` branch for. We use the latest version of `develop` but test them, make some bug fixes, adjust configurations etc.
   Only when everything is fine we actually merge onto `master` and therefore deploy to our users.

A final - but very important - note here:
`git-flow` is just one of many ways to organise your code. It's not a `this is the one and only solution for everyone and everything`. It's just a suggestions, a framework. Adjust it to your needs or use a completely different framework / idea if it does not work for you. I rarely used `git-flow` in the past 15 years **exactly** the way it's [documented](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). We always made some adjustments.
One of them btw being very closely related to your question: We would deploy from `release` and only if that deployment works and reached our clients (Apple's review process, I tell you!) we would merge to `master` and tag that release.